# Parsing hml. Spring Batch xml -> txt

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

How do I extract the following data from this xml? It has such a structure.

```
<ed:BICDirectoryEntry BIC="042007707"              >
    <ed:Accounts Account="30101810500000000707">
        <ed:RstrList AccRstr="URRS" AccRstrDate="2018-05-14"/>
        <ed:RstrList AccRstr="CLRS" AccRstrDate="2018-05-15"/>
    </ed:Accounts>
</ed:BICDirectoryEntry>
```

I need the datas.
BIC="042007707", AccRstrDate="2018-05-14"
I use Spring Batch

my reader

```
@Bean
    StaxEventItemReader<Bic> itemReader() {
        StaxEventItemReader<Bic> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<Bic>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("my.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[]{"Bic", "AccRstrDate"});
        Map<String, String> aliaseMap = new HashMap<>();
        aliaseMap.put("bic", "java.hello.Bic");
        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAliases(aliaseMap);
        reader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return reader;
    }
```

my writer

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Bic>()
                .name("itemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/output.txt"))
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                .build();
    }
```

Bic class.
It has in his body 2 parameters

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Bic {

    private String companyBic;
    private Date accRstrDate;

    public Bic() {
    }

    public Bic(String companyBic, String accRstrDate) {
        this.companyBic = companyBic;
        this.accRstrDate= accRstrDate;
    }

    public void setCompanyBic(String CompanyBic) {
        this.companyBic = companyBic;
    }

    public String getCompanyBic() {
        return companyBic;
    }


    public Date getaccRstrDate() {
        return accRstrDate;
    }

    public void setaccRstrDate(String accRstrDate) {
        accRstrDate= accRstrDate;
    }
}
```

please tell me is the correct reading and writing?

Comment: Can you share the code of the `Bic` type?

Comment: yes, sure. added to the main question

Comment: You `Bic` class has one field `accRstrDate` (which is not a list), but according to your document, there are multiple `RstrList` element instances each one with an attribute `AccRstrDate`. So, IMO this is not correct since you can't know which one to map. Moreover, can a `BICDirectoryEntry` have multiple `Accounts` elements? I think this type should be reflected in your java code.